# SVG object animation on a path line

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I want to animate a svg path on a line. Exactly like this codepen but instead of use a polygon, I want to use a more complex svg. (path) 
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/chris-creditdesign/pen/blJty)

Html :

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 300" enable-background="new 0 0 800 300" xml:space="preserve">

    <path d="M30,30 L770,30" />
    <path d="M29.833,113.5C29.833,178.667,99,271.334,257,271.334 S475.5,81,375.5,81S305,271.334,770,271.334"/>

    <polygon points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459    "/>

    <polygon points="15,0 18.541,11.459 30,11.459 20.729,18.541 24.271,30 15,22.918 5.729,30 9.271,18.541 0,11.459 11.459,11.459    "/>

</svg>
```

Is anyone know how to replace the polygon by a svg path file ?

Thank you,

Comment: You can use a bunch of different libraries that will accomplish this for you. 
SVGsnap
anime.js
https://greensock.com/
http://mojs.io/ to just name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I'm using a complex `<symbol>` element instead of the star. The `<symbol>` contains a path and 4 circles. I've putted this symbol in a hidden SVG element.

In the main SVG element I've changed the polygons (stars) with 2 `<use>` elements that are using the `#cow` symbol.

In the Javascript I've changed `var stars = svgContainer.getElementsByTagName("polygon");` with `var stars = svgContainer.getElementsByTagName("use");`

You can if you want to change the name of the variable from `stars` to `cows` in all your javascript.

```js
/* A variable to keep track of where we are on the line
 0 = start, 1 = end */
var counter = 0;

/* A boolean variable to keep track of the direction we want to travel in 
 true = move to the left, false move to the right */
var direction = true;

/* First get a reference to the enclosing div and then to
 the 2 svg paths */
var svgContainer = document.getElementById("outerWrapper");
var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = svgContainer.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, "path");
/* the var 'svg' contains a reference to two paths so svg.length = 2
 svg[0] is the straight line and svg[1] is the curved lines */

/* Now get the length of those two paths */
var straightLength = svg[0].getTotalLength();
var curveLength = svg[1].getTotalLength();

/* Also get a reference to the two star polygons */
var stars = svgContainer.getElementsByTagName("use");

function moveStar() {
 /* Check to see where the stars are journeys to determine 
  what direction they should be travelling in */
 if (parseInt(counter,10) === 1) {
  /* we've hit the end! */
  direction = false;
 } else if (parseInt(counter,10) < 0) {
  /* we're back at the start! */
  direction = true;
 }

 /* Based on the direction variable either increase or decrease the counter */
 if (direction) {
  counter += 0.003;
 } else {
  counter -= 0.003;
 }

 /* Now the magic part. We are able to call .getPointAtLength on the tow paths to return 
  the coordinates at any point along their lengths. We then simply set the stars to be positioned 
  at these coordinates, incrementing along the lengths of the paths */
 stars[0].setAttribute("transform","translate("+ (svg[0].getPointAtLength(counter * straightLength).x -15)  + "," + (svg[0].getPointAtLength(counter * straightLength).y -15) + ")");
 stars[1].setAttribute("transform","translate("+ (svg[1].getPointAtLength(counter * curveLength).x -15)  + "," + (svg[1].getPointAtLength(counter * curveLength).y -15) + ")");

 /* Use requestAnimationFrame to recursively call moveStar() 60 times a second
  to create the illusion of movement */
 requestAnimationFrame(moveStar);
}
requestAnimationFrame(moveStar);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #565279;
}

.outerWrapper {
 width: 800px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
}

.outerWrapper svg {
 position: absolute;
}

.outerWrapper svg path {
 fill:none; 
 stroke:#DABDD8;
 stroke-width:5; 
 stroke-dasharray:10,10;
}

.outerWrapper svg polygon {
 fill:orange; 
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none">
 <defs>  
<symbol id="cow" viewBox= "0 0 200 200">
 <path class="head" fill="gold" stroke-width="1" d="M87 110 c5 0 12-0 21-0 c9-0 26 2 33-4 c5-4 2-14 0-19 c-6-11-14-11-25-11c-10-0-15-7-8-16 c11-13 22-2 35-3 c7-0.622 15.812-11.692 5.757-14.441c-3.556-0.973-12.802 0.949-15.412-0.906c6.371 4.5 20.854-11.553 23.774-15.168 c4.103-5.079 7.713-10.561 10.987-16.205c0.678-1.169 2.928-7.366 4.133-7.882c-7.42 3.175-14.234 8.021-22.368 10.7 c-20.585 6.695-42.426 9.711-64.039 9.711c-18.865 0.045-41.083-2.831-60.479-8.723C16.774 10.2 9.1 5 0.6 1.4 C4.425 3 11 19.4 13.8 23.083c3.03 4 18.5 22.6 25.6 17.551c-2.173 1.544-10.67-0.021-13.562 0.5 c-9.382 1.672-7.292 11.8 1 14.308c12.151 3.7 23.371-8.617 35 0.611c7.217 5.7 11.1 18.941-1.428 19.4 c-10.27 0.355-20.138-1.575-26.384 8.23c-4.091 6.423-6.256 13.976-2.265 20.886c3.503 6.1 24.2 4.7 30.3 4.9 C70.382 109.8 78.7 109.9 87 109.8"/>
 
  <circle class="eyeR" fill="#040B13"  stroke-width="1"  cx="117.3" cy="64.9" r="6"/>
  <circle class="eyeL" fill="#040B13"  stroke-width="1"  cx="55.4" cy="64.9" r="6"/> 
  <circle class="nostrilL" fill="#446B70" stroke-width="1"  cx="50.6" cy="92.9" r="9"/> 
  <circle class="nostrilR" fill="#446B70"  stroke-width="1" cx="123.4" cy="92.9" r="9"/>
</symbol>
</defs> 
</svg>

<div class="outerWrapper" id="outerWrapper">

 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 300" enable-background="new 0 0 800 300" xml:space="preserve">
  
  <path class="pth" d="M30,30 L770,30" />
  <path class="pth" d="M29.833,113.5C29.833,178.667,99,271.334,257,271.334 S475.5,81,375.5,81S305,271.334,770,271.334"/>

  <use xlink:href="#cow" width="30" height="30" />
    <use xlink:href="#cow" width="30" height="30" />
 </svg>
       
</div>
```

Comment: Great thank you. I try to implant my svg and come back to you if I have any problem. 
Do you know how to automatically rotate the svg object in the direction of the path ?